# Jenkins job throws error when running protractor

Tags: jenkins, protractor

Get the following error when protractor is about to run on a windows host via jenkins job. We run selenium hub on a linux host with the selenium node running off of windows

```
               ^
`Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:172:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:271:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at net.js:459:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:157:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:131:30)
    at new Driver (C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:810:36)
    at [object Object].DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\direct.js:68:16)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:182:37)
    at C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:263:21
    at _fulfilled (C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:759:13)
    at C:\dependencies-dashboard\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:525:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: protractor exited with code 1
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`
```

Comment: I think it's due to Web Driver session not yet started or connection failure. You increase the time limit for job in Jenkins. It will resolve your problem

Comment: Definitely the problem is jenkins cannot reach selenium node on network level